# Search a stack recursively, but leave the stack intact

Tags: c++, search, recursion, stack

I have been trying to write a recursive function that searches a stack, but leaves the stack in its original state. I may pus
h and pop the stack, but not use a helper stack or any other data stucture.

And yes, this is homework, so I do not expect a complete coded answer :). A little help about how to approach the stack so that after the recursive search is finished the stack is intact would be appreciated.

The recursive function that searches the stack for a specified item(but destroys the stack) is given below:

```
template <class Type>

Type getNth(stack(Type) & s, int n)

{

    if(s.empty())
        return -1;
    if(s.top() == n)
        return s.top();
    if(s.top() != n && s.empty())
        return -1;
    else
        s.pop();
        return getNth(s, n);
}
```

This works, so far. 
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: +1 for not wanting people to do your homework for you :)

Comment: It is not related to the question, so I did not added it to the answer, but I think you have dead code in your last if statement, you can never enter it, because if s.empty() == true, then the first if would have been accessed and -1 would be returned.

Comment: If you can't use a stack as a helper data structure then you can't use recursion :)

Comment: @Seth Carnegie The question clearly states that I have to write a recursive function - and that I may NOT use any helper stack or other data structure. Could this be an error in the question?

Comment: @Seth: +1. True in any sane implementation. Linked lists, self-modifying code, etc all possible too though.

Comment: @JAR. It's a joke. He means that of course the helper data structure in recursion is the program stack with the scopes and function calls and so on. So, if you recurse you are using a stack which the compiler generates for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should store the `pop()`ed value, and the recursive call result, and `push()` the `pop()`ed value back, before returning.

your else should look something like that: [other than it, it looks fine]

```
else
    temp = s.pop();
    retVal =  getNth(s, n);
    s.push(temp);
    return retVal;
```

(*)forgive me for not declaring `temp` and `retVal`, You can understand the general idea from this..

---

EDIT:

I decided to add a simple example what is happening, assume your stack is

```
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|
---
```

and you are call getNth(s,3): this what will happen to the stack

after 1st pop() and getNth(): [stop condition was not reached, so keep going]

```
|2|
|3|
|4|
---
```

2nd pop(),getNth(): [again, keep going]

```
|3|
|4|
---
```

now, when you check if s.top() == n, you realize they are! so you return n.

when coming back from the recursion, `s.push(temp)` is called, and `temp==2`, so we get:

```
|2|
|3|
|4|
---
```

and we return retVal again, now back from the recursion, we use `s.push()` again, and we get:

```
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|
---
```

the original stack! and return the same returnVal, that was returned by the recursion!

**NOTE:** This is not your question, but the name of the function implies you don't want to return the value you were searching for, but rather the nth element in the stack, meaning, if your stack is:

```
|5|
|8|
|8|
|8|
|2|
|4|
---
```

`getNth(2)` will need to return 8, and NOT 2, as your question describes.

But I cannot possibly know that for sure, and if it is the case, I think you have enough tools to handle this question without too much problems!

good luck!

---

**EDIT 2:**

after the discussion in the comments, it is clear that the OP wanted something a bit different then what the original question describes, so therefore the extra edit:

Your solution is searching for an element and returns it, probably what you want to do is COUNT until these element, and then return, should be something like that [again, not declaring all variables, it won't compile, it's just a direction]:

```
template <class Type>
Type getNth(stack(Type) & s, int n)
{
    if(s.empty()) {return -1; } //note that in C++ throwing an exception here will be more wise, since -1 might be not matching to Type
    else if(n == 0) { return s.top(); }
    else {
        temp = s.pop();
        retVal = getNth(s, n-1);
        s.push(temp);
        return retVal;
   }
}
```

Comment: @JAR: It is not related to the question, so I did not added it to the answer, but I think you have dead code in your last if statement, you can never enter it, because if s.empty() == true, then the first if would have been accessed and -1 would be returned.

Comment: Thanks, that was quick.However, if I push the pop()ed value back before returning, will I not end up with same value?

Comment: Oh, didnt even see that - will check it out

Comment: @JAR: I am not sure I understand what you mean "will I not end up with the same value?"

Comment: @amir Sorry, I didn't make myself clear - if I push the popped value directly after I popped it, will I not end up reading the same element from the stack?

Comment: @amir oooohh - there is a light going up...thanks, that made it clearer - still not working though, I'll work on it for a bit

Comment: @amir - Thanks, that really helped a bunch - working like a charm now. To everyone that commented, thanks you guys!

Comment: @JAR: read my edit if you still don't understand how it works, I added a simple example. Also, the name of the function implies you understood the task wrong, but I am not sure about it :\

Comment: @amir - Your explanation is exactly what I was looking for - recursion and I generally do not see eye to eye :) Thanks again! I need to return the value of the nth element, according to the question i.e. the value stored in position 3, for example

Comment: @amir Yes you are indeed correct, my question was not quite correct, you understood it perfectly. Sorry for the extended posting, this is my first time on stackoverflow. Brilliant place!

Comment: @JAR: I editted my answer again [look under EDIT2], to give you direction in finding the nth problem, as we discussed in the comments.. Use it if you are stuck again! good luck!